# Commerce limit the quantity of product to 1

Tags: 8, commerce

I want to restrict quantity for certain products. Want to add a product only once in cart. How to achieve this?

There are 3 products in my store and I want the users to add only 1 product in the cart at a time.

Which hook do I need to use?

Comment: Its Drupal 8.5...

Comment: You want all products only once or is there any restriction of products to be added?

Answer (score 5):

What you will want to do is add an event subscriber to the Add to Cart event (https://github.com/drupalcommerce/commerce/blob/8.x-2.x/modules/cart/src/Event/CartEvents.php#L30).

Here is an example piece of code that would react to that event. This is for a Drupal Commerce site which only allowed purchasing one product at a time with a quantity of one.

```
/**
 * Sets quantity to 1 and ensures only one product in the cart.
 *
 * @param \Drupal\commerce_cart\Event\CartEntityAddEvent $event
 *   The cart event.
 */
public function onProductAdded(CartEntityAddEvent $event) {
  // We only want 1 quantity.
  $cart = $event->getCart();
  $added_order_item = $event->getOrderItem();
  $cart_items = $cart->getItems();
  foreach ($cart_items as $cart_item) {
    if ($cart_item->id() != $added_order_item->id()) {
      $cart->removeItem($cart_item);
      $cart_item->delete();
    }
  }

  $quantity = $cart_items[0]->getQuantity();
  if ($quantity > 1) {
    $cart_items[0]->setQuantity(1);
  }

  $cart->save();
}
```

Comment: This works really well - thanks!

Comment: Are you certain you should save the cart in onProductAdded()?

Comment: This is the best solution and could be completed with this documentation
https://docs.drupalcommerce.org/commerce2/developer-guide/cart/cart-events.

Answer (score 2):

Install the https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_xquantity and set the **max** property on the **/admin/commerce/config/order-item-types/YOUR_TYPE/edit/form-display/add_to_cart** page to 1 or any other value. So, once at a time clicking on the *Add to cart* button or editing quantity on the **/cart** page a customer can't add more than **max**.

But if you want overall to restrict the quantity on some variation then install the **Commerce Extended Quantity Stock**, the submodule of the above module. See more:
https://github.com/drugan/commerce_xquantity/tree/8.x-1.x/modules/xquantity_stock#commerce-extended-quantity-stock